# If both var have same value why it will show not equal

Tags: c, arrays, string

Here is my code can anyone tell me why the compiler prints "both are not  equal " message when I put the same value in both variable `a` and `b`.

(Note: I don't want to compare strings I just need the technical reason).

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char a[3]="abc",b[3]="abc";
    if(a==b)
        printf("both are equal");
    else
        printf("both are not equal");
}
```

Comment: OT but to store a string of 3 characters you should declare a[4] to leave space for the NULL end-of-string character. The others have answered the question

Answer (score 5):

C doesn't do string comparisons.  It will be comparing the two pointers that point to the start of the arrays, and they'll never be equal.

Use `strcmp()` to compare strings:

- `strcmp(a, b) == 0` for equality
- `strcmp(a, b) != 0` for inequality
- `strcmp(a, b) <  0` for `a` sorts before `b`
- `strcmp(a, b) <= 0` for `a` sorts before or is equal to `b`
- `strcmp(a, b) >  0` for `a` sorts after `b`
- `strcmp(a, b) >= 0` for `a` sorts after or is equal to `b`

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `b` are arrays and with the exception of *sizeof* and `&` they decay to pointers to the first element of the array and since they occupy different storage locations the pointer will not be equal. If we look at the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.3.2.1` *Lvalues, arrays, and function designators* paragraph *3* says (*emphasis mine*):

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a
>   string literal used to initialize an array, **an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is
>   converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of
>   the array object** and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the
>   behavior is undefined.

The [C FAQ question 6.3](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html) also covers this topic well.

The correct way to compare C style strings is to use [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp), from the linked document:

```
int strcmp( const char *lhs, const char *rhs );
```

and it is described as:

> Compares two null-terminated byte strings. The comparison is done lexicographically.

with the following return value:

- Negative value if lhs is less than rhs.

  ​0​ if lhs is equal to rhs.

  Positive value if lhs is greater than rhs.

Comment: C 2011 added another exception: `_Alignof`.

Answer (score 0):

Because their addresses are different (check the output [here](http://ideone.com/uHEK3E)) and if you intended to compare their values, it is better use [`strcmp(a,b)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

Comment: Using `strncmp` would be better (ie: work) given that the objects aren't really NUL-terminated strings.

Answer (score 0):

The name of an array is its address, not its content, thus, two different arrays, regardless of content, will 'miscompare'.

Comment: The name of an array names the array; it is not the array’s address. An array expression is automatically **converted** to a pointer to its first element except when it is the operand of `&`, `sizeof`, or `_Alignof` or is a string literal used to initialize an array.